# Can I revoke a Google OAuth2.0 access token WITHOUT invalidating its associated refresh token?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-identity

I have a setup that allows users to upload videos to my Youtube channel. The client requests an access token from my server, which uses a refresh token to generate said access token. The client then uses that access token to handle the video upload process. This token expires in 3600s by default, but I believe that still allows a would-be exploiter an adequate window to mess with my channel.

What I would like to do is revoke that user's access token as soon as their client has finished (or errored out of) the video upload process. I am already aware of the Google OAuth endpoint that allows you to revoke access tokens, but revoking an access token in that manner also revokes the refresh token used to generate it. Does anyone know of a simple way to do this via the Google API, or am I stuck recreating the entire Google OAuth2 workflow every time I want to revoke an access token?